# readonly parameter with container Class (C#)

Tags: c#, reference, readonly, data-containers

Ok so let's say that I have a data container class

```
public class DataContainer {
      public Person person;
}
```

and we already create an instance of this class

```
DataContainer dataContainer = new DataContainer();
dataContainer.Person = new Person("Smith");
```

and we try to pass it in a method that we want to be able to only read the container and not modified

```
public void ExampleMethod(in DataContainer dataContainer){
   dataConainer.Person.name = "blablabla" //we don't want to be able to do that
   dataContainer = new DataContainer(); // this is not possible because of in keyword
}
```

I tried the in keyword but it doesn't have any effect on prohibiting changes on container...

P.S. : convert the container into a struct is no solution because it will become immutable

Comment: That's not possible in C#. You can't have objects appear immutable in some contexts and mutable in others. I'd recommend making the field itself readonly, initialize it through its constructor, and accept immutable semantics everywhere.

Comment: You could make two interfaces: `IImmutablePerson` and `IMutablePerson` (examples) and have your person class implement both. For methods that are not supposed to make changes, use the immutable contract.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel The issue here is that I want other classes to be able to change data from the container , so a read-only field it doesn't sound good...
Maybe a getters and setters could do the work...
is it possible to detect who is getting the property? to restrict access from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to be able to modify the Person.Name, then you could simply use encapsulation.

I would design the Person class in the following way:

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

If this doesn't help, then the only other approach I see is to pass a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to `ExampleMethod` (which can be easily created using [Automapper](https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/)).

```
var dto = _mapper.Map<DataContainerDto>(dataContainer);
ExampleMethod(dto);

...

public void ExampleMethod(DataContainerDto dataContainer)
{
    // Nobody cares if I modify it,
    // because the original dataContainer reamains intact
    dataConainer.Person.name = "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: that's looks good! actually maybe is what I am looking for... so I am going to give it a try!
thanks a lot!